# Remove Zero From the HIGHCHART

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been working on Highcharts just got into one trouble the problem is when there is not any value exist for some data on the chart then it displays 0 on it which looks bad kindly checkout the following jsfiddle the labels on the chart gets populated by the following function but i am not able to put check on it that it should display only those bars whose values are above zero on the chart

http://jsfiddle.net/CzHyC/3/   [KINDLY CHECK THE APPLE section on the chart]

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'blue'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -100,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'gray',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [0, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the way I have dealt with this situation.

When you are creating your data points, instead of putting a 0, put a null.

So for example your data array will look like:

`[null,3,4,7,2]` instead of `[0,3,4,7,2]`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzHyC/8/)

Comment: good trick but the data is being populated in my chart from DB but i can put checks on that

Comment: yes, you will have to build your data in a specific format before giving it to highcharts.

Comment: I would have set the value to null. Remember that -1 is a value whereas null is not.